# ChartJS adding 3yAxes

Tags: php, chart.js

I try to make this chart, the issue is that I need more y-axis because stock data and reviews/price but looks like after I try to do this the chart is not loading, what I tried is to add: `yAxisID: '#name#'` to each dataset.

So I want to add a y-axis for Price, one for Reviews and one for Rank.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "/data.php",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);

            var stock = [];
            var price = [];
            var reviews = [];
            var date = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                stock.push(data[i].stock);
                price.push(data[i].price);
                reviews.push(data[i].rating);
                date.push(data[i].scrape_date);
            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: date,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "price",
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0.1,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.75)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                        data: price


                    },
                    {
                        label: "reviews",
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0.1,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 0.75)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
                        data: reviews

                    },
                    {
                        label: "stock",
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0.1,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 0.75)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
                        data: stock

                    }
                ]
            };
            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {

                data: chartdata
            });
        },
        error : function(data) {

        }
    });
});
```

and here is my **`data.php`** data:

```
[{"stock":"100","price":"9.99","rating":"5","best_seller_rank":"40","scrape_date":"2017-07-05 17:22:00"},{"stock":"93","price":"9.99","rating":"5","best_seller_rank":"291","scrape_date":"2017-07-07 00:44:00"},{"stock":"93","price":"9.99","rating":"5","best_seller_rank":"563","scrape_date":"2017-07-07 16:47:00"},{"stock":"92","price":"9.99","rating":"5","best_seller_rank":"495","scrape_date":"2017-07-08 17:44:00"},{"stock":"90","price":"9.99","rating":"5","best_seller_rank":"641","scrape_date":"2017-07-09 20:28:00"},{"stock":"1000","price":"9.99","rating":"5","best_seller_rank":"899","scrape_date":"2017-07-10 17:51:00"},{"stock":"83","price":"9.99","rating":"5","best_seller_rank":"973","scrape_date":"2017-07-11 18:20:00"},{"stock":"79","price":"9.99","rating":"5","best_seller_rank":"575","scrape_date":"2017-07-12 19:32:00"},{"stock":"76","price":"9.99","rating":"5","best_seller_rank":"970","scrape_date":"2017-07-13 16:03:00"},{"stock":"77","price":"9.99","rating":"5","best_seller_rank":"845","scrape_date":"2017-07-14 16:26:00"},{"stock":"72","price":"9.99","rating":"7","best_seller_rank":"255","scrape_date":"2017-07-17 13:09:00"},{"stock":"64","price":"9.99","rating":"8","best_seller_rank":"999","scrape_date":"2017-07-19 14:41:00"},{"stock":"1000","price":"9.99","rating":"8","best_seller_rank":"55","scrape_date":"2017-07-20 18:37:00"},{"stock":"58","price":"9.99","rating":"8","best_seller_rank":"39","scrape_date":"2017-07-21 12:56:00"},{"stock":"1000","price":"9.99","rating":"8","best_seller_rank":"983","scrape_date":"2017-07-24 01:55:00"},{"stock":"36","price":"9.99","rating":"8","best_seller_rank":"428","scrape_date":"2017-07-24 23:26:00"},{"stock":"1000","price":"9.99","rating":"8","best_seller_rank":"294","scrape_date":"2017-07-27 11:15:00"},{"stock":"8","price":"9.99","rating":"8","best_seller_rank":"11","scrape_date":"2017-07-29 16:09:00"},{"stock":"1","price":"9.99","rating":"8","best_seller_rank":"13","scrape_date":"2017-07-31 21:01:00"},{"stock":"65","price":"9.99","rating":"8","best_seller_rank":"15","scrape_date":"2017-08-01 23:33:00"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chart is not loading because, you haven't defined the chart type *(bar, line etc.)*.

SO, define the chart type, as such :

```
...
var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
         type: 'line',
         data: chartdata,
         ...
```

Now, to add three y-axis, first you need to set **`yAxisID`** for each dataset, like so :

```
...
datasets: [{
   ...,
   yAxisID: 'price'
}, {
   ...,
   yAxisID: 'reviews'
}, {
   ...,
   yAxisID: 'stock'
}]
...
```

then, add three separate y-axis and set their id in your chart options, as such :

```
options: {
   scales: {
      yAxes: [{
         id: 'price'
      }, {
         id: 'reviews'
      }, {
         id: 'stock'
      }]
   }
}
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: "https://istack.000webhostapp.com/json/t12.json",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);

         var stock = [];
         var price = [];
         var reviews = [];
         var date = [];

         for (var i in data) {
            stock.push(data[i].stock);
            price.push(data[i].price);
            reviews.push(data[i].rating);
            date.push(data[i].scrape_date);
         }

         var chartdata = {
            labels: date,
            datasets: [{
               label: "price",
               fill: false,
               lineTension: 0.1,
               backgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.75)",
               borderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
               pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
               pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
               data: price,
               yAxisID: 'price'

            }, {
               label: "reviews",
               fill: false,
               lineTension: 0.1,
               backgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 0.75)",
               borderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
               pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
               pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
               data: reviews,
               yAxisID: 'reviews'

            }, {
               label: "stock",
               fill: false,
               lineTension: 0.1,
               backgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 0.75)",
               borderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
               pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
               pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
               data: stock,
               yAxisID: 'stock'
            }]
         };
         var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

         var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: chartdata,
            options: {
               scales: {
                  yAxes: [{
                     id: 'price'
                  }, {
                     id: 'reviews'
                  }, {
                     id: 'stock'
                  }]
               }
            }
         });
      },
      error: function(data) {

      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hey thank you looks like this is the solution , just quick question:   label: "reviews",   type: "bar", i try to make reviews to be bar mode , but it will not display that  :-?

Comment: are you trying to make combined bar and line chart?

Comment: yes , and from the examples just adding a different type to the price dataset for example would work

Comment: in that case, you need to set the main chart type to bar, and then set the type to line for those datasets that you wish to be in line mode. see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/atkc3579/)